# get datatable row data & column in comma,pipe separated format

Tags: c#

i have C# `DataTable` in format as below

```
Name    Value1  Value2  Value3
A          5       5    0
B          6       3    1
C          4       9    9
```

Expected format in string should be as

```
string sDataTableOutput = "A,B,C|Value1,5,6,4|Value2,5,3,9|Value3,0,1,9";
```

I want Column Header with data (except for first column)

i try hard to write below code but couldnt get it done

```
DataTable dtGraphOutput[0] = //Get DataTable Data ; 

foreach (DataColumn dcOutput in dtGraphOutput[0].Columns)
{
    foreach (DataRow drOutput in dtGraphOutput[0].Rows)
    {                                        
        sTicketTypeCount += ((sTicketTypeCount == "") ? "" : ",") + dcOutput.ColumnName + Convert.ToString(drOutput[dcOutput]);
    }
    sTicketTypeCount += ((sTicketTypeCount == "") ? "" : "|");
}
```

Its giving me output as

```
NameA,NameB,NameC|,Value15,Value16,Value14|,Value25,Value23,Value29|,Value30,Value31,Value39|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is LINQ and gives you the desired result:

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable();
var firstCol = string.Join(",", rows.Select(r => r.Field<string>(0)));
var otherColumns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(1)
    .Select(dc => string.Format("{0},{1}", 
        dc.ColumnName, 
        string.Join(",", rows.Select(r => r.Field<int>(dc)))));
string sDataTableOutput = string.Format("{0}|{1}", 
    firstCol, 
    string.Join("|", otherColumns));
```

Result: `A,B,C|Value1,5,6,4|Value2,5,3,9|Value3,0,1,9`

Comment: error `The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments` and `cannot convert from 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' to 'string[]'`

Comment: @SagarDumbre: Are you're using .NET 3.5? Then you cannot use [`String.Join` with an `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) and you have to use [the one that takes an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.80).aspx). For example: `string.Join("|", otherColumns.ToArray()));`. The same on the other `string.Join`s.

Comment: Which to use then i have option 3.5 or 4 or 4.5

Comment: @SagarDumbre: You need at least .NET 4 if you want to use the overload with an `IEnumerable<T>` which is more efficient. Then the above code compiles and works directly without any modification.

Comment: I have changed it to 4 Now it gives me error in runtime `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.`

Comment: @SagarDumbre: You haven't mentioned what type the columns have. If they are not strings you need to change it accordingly. For example: `r.Field<string>(dc)` to `r.Field<int>(dc)`

Comment: Except for First column all are int

Answer (score 1):

```
string sDataTableOutput = string.Join("|", 
                           dtGraphOutput[0].Columns
                                           .OfType<DataColumn>()
                                           .Select((c,i) =>
                                              string.Join(",",
                                              dtGraphOutput[0].Rows
                                                              .OfType<DataRow>()
                                                              .Select((r,j)=>
                                                          (j == 0 && i != 0 ? c.ColumnName + "," : "") + r[c.ColumnName])
                                                              .ToArray())).ToArray());
                                                                             .
```

Comment: why does it give me multiple error some of it are `'System.Data.DataColumn' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field<T>(System.Data.DataRow, string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @SagarDumbre sorry, I typed the `c` instead of `r`, just updated.

Comment: error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'`

Comment: @SagarDumbre that's because your column values are `Int32`, just edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable dtGraphOutput[0] = //Get DataTable Data ; 

foreach (DataColumn dcOutput in dtGraphOutput[0].Columns)
{
    sTicketTypeCount +=dcOutput.ColumnName
    foreach (DataRow drOutput in dtGraphOutput[0].Rows)
    {                                        
        sTicketTypeCount += ","+ dcOutput.ColumnName + Convert.ToString(drOutput[dcOutput]);
    }
    sTicketTypeCount += ((sTicketTypeCount == "") ? "" : "|");
}
```

if you have problem with the last "|" you can remove it with a simple if

Comment: it doesnt give desired output i want final string as `A,B,C|Value1,5,6,4|Value2,5,3,9|Value3,0,1,9`

Comment: slight change of what i wrote in question i.e. `NameA,NameB,NameC|,Value15,Value16,Value14|,Value25,Value23,Value29|,Value30,Value31,Value39|
`

Comment: if you mean that it gives you "NameA" instead of "A". you can change the name of column to "A". if not give the result of my codes.